# What is "Four Part" Harmony?

Tags: harmony, voice, terminology

Can someone explain “four part” harmony and its difference or/and its relation to regular harmony? I’ve been searching the internet and can’t find any information that clearly answers my question towards the subject.

Comment: Apologies in advance: it's what you get when you sing along with Three Dog Night.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNglSUBkduA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any harmony is more than one voice, or instrument sounding simultaneously, producing different notes which blend melodiously together.

Four part harmony comes from four voices originally, the highest being two female voices - soprano and alto, under which comes tenor and bass. Each has its own line of music, which is followed, along with the others singing simultaneously. It's usually written out as soprano, stems up, alto stems down on treble clef, and tenor, stems up, bass stems down on the bass clef stave.

It doesn't have to be human voices - it can be instruments, each of which follows its own line of music.

Comment: Also   SPEBSQSA   .........

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - you're being rather esoteric! What?

Comment: it **is** googleable :-) .   What fun would it be if I gave it away?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - for you, probably none. Can't spend my time googling - I have other things to do! You started it..!

Comment: @Tim.hee hee we both waste our time on SE but no time to do research :-)

Answer (score 4):

"Harmony" is a generic term for the result of putting multiple sounds together at the same time. "Four part" harmony essentially means that there are four simultaneous tones involved. More specifically, "Four part" harmony derives from vocal music arranged for four voices: soprano, alto, tenor, bass.